# How to change column title using Dynamic View Panel customizer bean?

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino, xpages-extlib

I am using a **Dynamic View Panel** to display various views inside a single XPage. I am using customizer bean to change date format, number format etc. on documents and it works fine.
Now I want to change/translate column **titles**, but I don't have an idea how to set different column title using customizer bean. Has somebody already solved that issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override 'createColumn' method and adjust the column information. You just need to cast ColumnDef  arg3 argument to DefaultColumnDef so you can update some properties. Then you have to send this updated DefaultColumnDef object into former createColumn method ...

```
@Override
public IControl createColumn(FacesContext arg0, UIDynamicViewPanel arg1,int arg2, ColumnDef arg3) {

  DefaultColumnDef dc=(DefaultColumnDef) arg3;
  dc.title=arg3.getTitle()+"some your text";

  // send DefaultColumn object into former createColumn method ...
  IControl col = super.createColumn(arg0, arg1, arg2, dc);      
  return col;
}
```